# Regular expression to capture different lines

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to find a better way to capture variable values from a file that stores some information but facing the problem with line breaks and spaces. For example, a **DataSetList** variable is given that stores a value in two different ways:

### Input

```
Templates = <
  item
    Name = 'fruits'
    TemplateList = '7,12'
  end>
Surveys = <
  item
    ID = 542
    Name = 'apple'
  end
  item
    ID = 872
    Name = 'banana'
    DataSetList = '873,887,971,1055'
    PluginInfo = {something}
  end
  item
    ID = 437
    Name = 'cherry'
    DataSetList = 
      '438,452,536,620,704,788,1143,1179,1563,1647,1731,1839,1875,1851,' +
      '1863,2060,2359,2443,2469,2620'
    PluginInfo = {something}
  end>
```

The only way i've found to **capture** the values of the variables **ID**, **Name**, **DataSetList** variable values that are stored in **'item end' block** is ([My approach](https://regex101.com/r/XGRZhZ/1)):

### Expression

```
ID[\s\=]*(?P<UID>\d*)\s*Name[\s\=]*'(?P<Name>.*)'\s*DataSetList[\s\=]*(?P<DataSetList>(?:'[\d\,]*'[\s\+]*)*)
```

```
ID[\s\=]*(?P<UID>\d*)                                    # capture ID
\s*                                                      # match spaces 
Name[\s\=]*'(?P<Name>.*)'                                # capture Name
\s*                                                      # match spaces
DataSetList[\s\=]*(?P<DataSetList>(?:'[\d\,]*'[\s\+]*)*) # capture DataSetList
```

### My approach output

```
{'UID': '872',
 'Name': 'banana',
 'DataSetList': "'873,887,971,1055'\n    "}

{'UID': '437',
 'Name': 'cherry',
 'DataSetList': "'438,452,536,620,704,788,1143,1179,1563,1647,1731,1839,1875,1851,' +\n      '1863,2060,2359,2443,2469,2620'\n    "}
```

### Problem

I don't think [my approach](https://regex101.com/r/XGRZhZ/1) is good because named capturing group DataSetList also captures spaces, line breaks, literal + and finally requires postprocessing of values.

Any approaches or ideas to improve my regular expression would be very helpful. Unfortunately my knowledge base of regex isn't as deep as i would like it to be. It's very interesting to see how it's done in other ways

Comment: you've given the output for 'avocado' but not the input - would make it easier to understand the question

Comment: @akash I thought that was enough as an example drawing attention to the DataSetList variable but I agree that it can be a bit confusing. I'll fix that, thanks.

Comment: This regex you're using does not look bad. I tried to write something wihtout looking to your current pattern before and came up [with this (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/OIN5eL/1) which is very similar. Of course you'd need a bit further processing but everything looks good imho. With [PyPI regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) you could use something with [`\G`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) and [`\K`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) like [that demo](https://regex101.com/r/tsZGfH/1) but I guess this will just complicate things when parsing the output. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can improve the regex a bit.

```
ID[\s=]*(?P<UID>\d*)\s*Name[\s=]*'(?P<Name>.*)'\s*DataSetList[\s=]*(?P<DataSetList>'(?:[\d,]|'[\s+]*')*')
```

This gets rid of the unnecessary `=` and `,` escapes. The last part now won't match the whitespace after the final bit of the `DataSetList`.

I can't see a nice way to avoid having to post-process the `DataSetList`, if you stick to regular expressions.

If you need to do anything more complicated with this, I'd advise moving away from regexes. They are great for simple things, but it looks like in this case you'd be better off with a proper parser. If none already exists for the language you have here, you can use a parsing library such as [Lark](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create one without too much difficulty.

Comment: I had hoped regular expressions would suffice but the structure of the input file is more complicated than in the example, I'll listen to your advice on looking a proper parser